# UICollectionView auto adjusts to be at index, instead of part of each.

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, autoscroll

I was wondering if there was a way to make a UICollectionView auto go to the next closest indexPath only if the user has stopped scrolling and has landed in between two cells, shown below:

This is an image of where the auto scroll would need to come in because there in between cells:
[image]

And here is a photo of the desired landing position:

[image]

If you guys have anything that could help that would be greatly appreciated. If you think you might be able to help but don't understand what I'm asking just let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way to do this, you need to recreate the `paging` functionality. You should look at this [link](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/stevez/archive/2014/05/13/ios-objective-c-custom-paging-with-uiscrollview-using-the-iggridview.aspx). Below is what it could look like in your case, assuming that it's a vertical scroll:

```
#pragma mark - UIScrollViewDelegate

- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UICollectionView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset {

    float cellHeight = 130; // Replace this value with your cell height + line spacing between cells
    float val = (scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.contentInset.top) / cellHeight;
    int newPage = val;


    if (velocity.x == 0) {
        newPage = floor((targetContentOffset->y - cellHeight / 2) / cellHeight) + 1;

    } else {
        if (velocity.x < 0) {

            CGFloat diff = val - newPage;
            if (diff > .5f)
                newPage++;
        }

        newPage = MAX(0, velocity.x > 0 ? newPage + 1 : newPage - 1);

        if (newPage > scrollView.contentSize.height / cellHeight)
            newPage = ceil(scrollView.contentSize.height / cellHeight) - 1.f;
    }

    *targetContentOffset = CGPointMake(targetContentOffset->x, (int)(newPage * cellHeight));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to get the visible cells and scroll to the one of the next neighbors by hand.

something like:

```
NSArray *visiblePaths = [self.collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems];
[self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[visiblePaths firstObject] atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
```